# Issue displaying font with java swing

Tags: java, swing, fonts, attributes, awt

#### Hi,

So there is my problem :
I can't understand why this little program :

```
package tests;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.text.AttributedCharacterIterator.Attribute;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

final class FontTest implements Runnable {
    public static void main(String[]arguments_) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new FontTest());
    }
    private String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame_ = new JFrame("FontTest");
        JPanel panel_ = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2));
        JTextArea area_1 = new JTextArea(), area_2 = new JTextArea();
        Font[]all_fonts = GraphicsEnvironment
                       .getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getAllFonts();
        // picking 2 fonts with different predefined specificities
        // Arial Bold Italic and Bahnschrift Bold Condensed
        Font font_1 = all_fonts[6], font_2 = all_fonts[13];
        Map<? extends Attribute, ?> map_1 = font_1.getAttributes()
                                  , map_2 = font_2.getAttributes();
        setTextArea(area_1, new Font(map_1));
        setTextArea(area_2, new Font(map_2));
        panel_.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1080, 240));
        panel_.add(area_1);
        panel_.add(area_2);
        frame_.add(panel_);
        frame_.pack();
        frame_.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame_.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame_.setVisible(true);
    }
    private void setTextArea(JTextArea area_, Font font_) {
        area_.setFont(font_.deriveFont(14.f));
        area_.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(area_.getFont().getName()));
        area_.append(newLine);
        for(Object o : area_.getFont().getAttributes().entrySet()) {
            area_.append(o.toString());
            area_.append(newLine);
        }
        area_.append(newLine);
        area_.append(area_.getFont().toString());
        for(Attribute a : font_.getAvailableAttributes()) {
            System.out.println(a);
        }
    }
}
```

is showing this when executing :
[JFrame showing 2 Fonts thru their name, attributes, and constructor, both irrelevant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uX6tl.png)

- Why `TextAttribute` are `null` for width, posture and weight (and all others except size and family) since font's name suggests some value ?
- Why the constructors (`font_.toString()`) describe a plain style since they should be bold+italic or bold ?
- Why the first Font (Arial) is actually bold and italic since its attributes AND constructor say it's not ?
- Why the second Font (Bahnschrift) is neither bold nor condensed, since its attributes AND constructor are the same than the first Font ?

Please, thanks to help me understanding that...

Edit :

```
for(Attribute a : font_.getAvailableAttributes()) {
    System.out.println(a);
}
```

- for the first font (Arial Bold Italic) :

```
java.awt.font.TextAttribute(family)
java.awt.font.TextAttribute(weight)
java.awt.font.TextAttribute(width)
java.awt.font.TextAttribute(posture)
java.awt.font.TextAttribute(size)
java.awt.font.TextAttribute(transform)
java.awt.font.TextAttribute(superscript)
java.awt.font.TextAttribute(char_replacement)
java.awt.font.TextAttribute(foreground)
java.awt.font.TextAttribute(background)
java.awt.font.TextAttribute(underline)
java.awt.font.TextAttribute(strikethrough)
java.awt.font.TextAttribute(run_direction)
java.awt.font.TextAttribute(bidi_embedding)
java.awt.font.TextAttribute(justification)
java.awt.font.TextAttribute(input method highlight)
java.awt.font.TextAttribute(input method underline)
java.awt.font.TextAttribute(swap_colors)
java.awt.font.TextAttribute(numeric_shaping)
java.awt.font.TextAttribute(kerning)
java.awt.font.TextAttribute(ligatures)
java.awt.font.TextAttribute(tracking)
```

- And for the second one (Bahnschrift Bold Condensed) :

```
java.awt.font.TextAttribute(family)
java.awt.font.TextAttribute(weight)
java.awt.font.TextAttribute(width)
java.awt.font.TextAttribute(posture)
java.awt.font.TextAttribute(size)
java.awt.font.TextAttribute(transform)
java.awt.font.TextAttribute(superscript)
java.awt.font.TextAttribute(char_replacement)
java.awt.font.TextAttribute(foreground)
java.awt.font.TextAttribute(background)
java.awt.font.TextAttribute(underline)
java.awt.font.TextAttribute(strikethrough)
java.awt.font.TextAttribute(run_direction)
java.awt.font.TextAttribute(bidi_embedding)
java.awt.font.TextAttribute(justification)
java.awt.font.TextAttribute(input method highlight)
java.awt.font.TextAttribute(input method underline)
java.awt.font.TextAttribute(swap_colors)
java.awt.font.TextAttribute(numeric_shaping)
java.awt.font.TextAttribute(kerning)
java.awt.font.TextAttribute(ligatures)
java.awt.font.TextAttribute(tracking)
```

Comment: What does [getAvailableAttributes](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Font.html#getAvailableAttributes()) return for each of those fonts?

Comment: I edited my post to show that...

Comment: I did some testing, and it appears the only attributes returned are those provided when the font was created (that is, those provided to the Font constructor or the deriveFont method);  apparently no attempt is made to read the attributes from the font definition itself.

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid about something like that. `new Font("Arial Bold Italic", Font PLAIN, 14)` returns a bold and italic `Font`, despite `Font.PLAIN` in it... But... Paint, from Windows in its  font chooser recognize the one causing trouble here : it proposes "Bahnschrift Bold Condensed" with bold and condensed glyphes.... So there must be a way??? May be not in java...

Comment: And also, it doesn't explain why the Arial font is displayed with its attributes named but not mapped, whereas the Bahnschrift one is not...